# ExtGwt dynamically changing size of ContentPanel

Tags: gwt, layout, alignment, gxt

While creating a small aplication in ExtGwt I've bumped into such problem:

Is there any way to center the content of the ContentPanel horizontally (and only horizontally) ?

I know the one solution is to use:

```
ContentPanel panel = new ContentPanel();
panel.setLayout(new CenterLayout());
//but here is the problem, I MUST set the size of panel
panel.setSize(400, 200);
```

However, I need this panel to have dinamically calculated height, because it has different content in various places.

Other thing is to use UIBinder, but that's somehow also not a good idea.

Anyone has idea how to achieve such solution?

Comment: "Other thing is to use UIBinder, but that's somehow also not a good idea". What??

Comment: @travis-webb It was not a good idea, because in project we assumed that we do not want to use UIBinder. I didn't say that this tool is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

layout the `ContentPanel` inside its container with a `FitLayout`. that way, the `ContentPanel`'s size is always managed, and you won't have to specify it's dimensions.

```java
public class ContentPanelContainer extends LayoutContainer {

    @Override
    protected void onRender(Element parent, int index) {
        super.onRender(parent, index);

        setLayout(new FitLayout());

        ContentPanel panel = new ContentPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new CenterLayout());

        add(panel);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In fact I needed it in a few hours after I asked the question. We (team project) decided, to stay with static height of content.
However, we were working with FitLayout() for a second, but it still wasn't really what we were looking for (Website looked like box-on-box centered-column). Well but so far your answer, surely, may help others. Cheers!